# Python list doesn't work with loop when definition of desired list value is added

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking to have a list of items eventually be ran through a function one at a time. For the below example if I have print(count) it gives me a solid 0, 1, 2. But when I add the new definition of print(host) it only produces alpha, alpha, alpha. For some reason it seems as though the count is stuck at 0? Am I missing something obvious here or is there a better way to do this?

```
greek_list = ["alpha", "beta", "kappa"]


count = 0
host = (greek_list[count])

while count < 3:
    print(host)
    count += 1
```

Comment: You never update `host`. You are updating `count`, only, but that doesn't mean the `greek_list[count]` expression is re-executed. That's not part of the loop.

Comment: In other words, if you updated `count`, and want `host` updated too, you'll have to execute the `host = greek_list[count]` expression again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could try to put the `host` variable inside the while:

```
greek_list = ["alpha", "beta", "kappa"]
count = 0
while count < 3:
    host = (greek_list[count])
    print(host)
    count += 1
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

if you're wanting to print the values in `greek_list` use a `for` loop.

try

```
greek_list = ["alpha", "beta", "kappa"]
while for x in geek_list:
    print(x)
```